# After FB login review, iOS app can share, but not like

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In April 2015, we have submitted an iOS app with Graph API v2.2 for Facebook Login review for `publish_actions` permission. It has been approved, we have set YES for "Do you want this app ... to be available for general public".

But now only users with Testers and Developers roles can *both* **share** and **like**.
"General public" users can only **share** (very strange).

In code, we surely do request `publish_actions`.

How can we allow regular users to post likes?

Comment: Are you using the Native Like Button? If so then you need to submit for review before the public can use it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button#review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that our app used to post likes not through the FB SDK's like button, but through our own button via the graph API.

So we had to submit open-graph action type Like as well as permissions.

It's very misleading, that `publish_actions` permission does not cover the very ability to post likes.

P.S. As of the April, 2015, to add Likes to submission, you should go to `Status & Review` -> `Items in Review` -> `Add Items to this Submission` -> `Action types` -> `"Like" checkbox`. Than add like-related screenshots from your app.

Note, that it is prohibited to use custom "thumbs-up"-looking icon for your custom like button (FB brand restrictions), use "heart" icon or so.

Comment: Hi Andrey,
can you post the source where you found about the publish_actions + Like Action thing?
Also, will they stop access to graph api if we use thumbs up kinda icon. Have you tried that?

Comment: @iSaalis, sorry, can not remember. I have not worked with Facebook for almost a year already. My advice is to google thoroughly and read FB's Graph API docs a lot. You will find a lot of interesting information there, so it is a strong advice. Also I am afraid that my year-old knowledge could be anyway useless because of FB's API deprecation policy.

Comment: @iSaalis, Thumbs-looking icon will not prevent you from using Graph API during development. But FB will reject your app when it comes on review.